# How can I change the border color of my OptionMenu in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble changing the border/outline color of the Tkinter OptionMenu widget. I've uploaded a picture of what it currently looks like (NES.png is the text for the drop down menu):
[My Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCwKl.png)

I would like the sheer white border/outline to not exist, but I can not seem to find a parameter to do so. Here is my current code:

```
dropdown = tk.OptionMenu(parent, variable, default, *list)
dropdown.config(bg=color, fg="white", activebackground=select_color)
dropdown["menu"].config(bg=color, fg="white")
dropdown.grid(padx=self.padding, pady=self.spacing)
```

The "color" variable is currently set to a dark red color, and "select_color" is currently set to a bright red color. Is there any way to fix this? I am having the same problem with my slider/scale as well.

Comment: maybe kwarg: `bd=0` would help (for other widgets such argument would set their borderwidth to 0 pixels), so like: `dropdown.config(bd=0)`

Comment: Have you tried setting the `highlightcolor`? That looks to be the highlight ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Bryan Oakley in the comments mentioned that it might be the highlightcolor. I tried changing the color of that, and it didn't change anything. Intellisense, however, saved the day. It suggested using highlightbackground and highlightthickness, either of which I can use to hide the outline.